# Software for Plantronics Gamecom 788 Headset

Tags: sound, headset

I have a [Plantronics Gamecom 788](http://www.plantronics.com/us/product/gc780-surround-sound-windows) 7.1 emulated surround sound headset, and I'm trying to find out if anyone knows if there is a way to make this work in Ubuntu. Plantronics has the software for Windows that works great, I just don't know if there is anything for Linux that would make this work. Stereo works great, but not 7.1 surround.

If it doesn't work I can live with it, but if anyone knows of any software out there that'd be great!

Thanks!

Comment: Hmmmm....forgive me just how can a left/right headphone possibly work/sound like an open air surround 7.1 system?

Comment: @mdpc That's actually the wrong question. It should rather be: Given that we can model sound for very precisely perceived directionality using only a headset, why is marketing so utterly stupid and calls it 7.1?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a typical USB stereo headset.

If it doesn't offer any special modes in `alsamixer` or the Windows software/driver blob enables some proprietary mode that makes it receive multichannel audio and processing audio on the device or cable plug, then stereo is all you will ever get. "Emulated surround sound" as you already said.

You could – no, you better *should* – contact the the manufacturers customer support and tell them that you expect this to work on non-Microsoft operating systems, too. (Creative for example offers Android and IOs apps.) Probably at some point in time the proprietary technology gets licensed for other platforms and the *"customer experience"* gets ported.

I don't want to sound like I'm ranting, but the choice of calling it 7.1 is so unbelievably ambiguous. I remember older 5.1 headsets being sold with 3 drivers per ear, which were technically 4.2 and upgrades to that would be 6.2 or 8.2, but if the driver or virtual speaker count doesn't matter why not just go ahead and call it [Atmos](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dolby_Atmos) Portable or Atmos Gaming? It certainly must be a mixture of fear about watering down the high end line of brands, not being confident about the the capabilities of the software, or to expensive for the licensee. In the meantime new companies are [trying hard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AMD_TrueAudio). :(